# Dynamic comments for Hologram with SASS

Tags: sass

I am including [Hologram](https://github.com/trulia/hologram) in a current project, where we already use SASS (with compass).

We have a list of colors used in the project :

```
$colors:
    "white" #FFF,
    "black" #000,
    "grey" #A9A9A9;
```

I'm trying to get my hologram documentation to look like this :

```
/*doc
---
title: Colors
name: Colors
category: Base CSS
---

List of the colors used.

<div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="color-cube white"></div>
    <code>$white</code>
</div>

<div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="color-cube black"></div>
    <code>$black</code>
</div>

<div class="cube-wrapper">
    <div class="color-cube grey"></div>
    <code>$grey</code>
</div>

*/
```

This is as far as I could get using sass loops ([SassMeister link](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8c44b6b0034c73060b5a)):

```
/*doc
---
title: Colors
name: Colors
category: Base CSS
---

List of the colors used.

*/

@each $i in $colors {
    /*
    <div class="cube-wrapper">
        <div class="color-cube #{nth($i, 1)}"></div>
        <code>$#{nth($i, 1)}</code>
    </div>
    */
}

@each $i in $colors {
    .#{nth($i, 1)} {
        background-color: nth($i, 2);
    }
}
```

Problem is, I'm closing my comments before I even write the HTML that Hologram will use. So Hologram only picks up the top part.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the last index then add `*/`

```
/*doc
---
 title: Colors
 name: Colors
 category: Base CSS
---

List of the colors used.



@for $i from 1 through length($colors)  {

    <div class="cube-wrapper">
        <div class="color-cube #{nth($i, 1)}"></div>
        <code>$#{nth($i, 1)}</code>
    </div>
   @if length($colors)
    */
}

@each $i in $colors {
    .#{nth($i, 1)} {
        background-color: nth($i, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work? I get `SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "     *\"  : expected selector or at-rule, was }`